# MVC: How are people organizing routes in production level scenarios

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to MVC and still trying got work out the best practices while working on a small MVC doc generator inside our intranet which is developed based on web forms. I was wondering how people are managing the routes for production level sites. I was reading Phil Haack's [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/17/editable-routes.aspx) on separating routes but again just wondering how others are doing the work. There must be some good practices around by now which I don't know of. Tips, links and suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: check out http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm becoming a fan of Attribute-based routing.  [This particular article](http://kevinmontrose.com/2011/07/25/why-i-love-attribute-based-routing/) by Kevin from the SO team was really helpful and got us kickstarted down this path.  For us keeping the routing policies close to the handlers makes maintenance a lot easier and avoids lint from developing.  You can also easily unit test the route handling per Controller.

Comment: BTW, this is now out under http://attributerouting.net, supporting MVC and Web API.